# Computing an improper integral

Tags: real-analysis

I think that I want to use integration by parts for this, but I'm unsure. We have
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\alpha x)\cos(\beta x)}{x}dx$$ and we know that a, b, are positive real numbers.
I was also considering using properties of trig to make a substitution, but I think that would actually get messier.

Answer (score 1):

In the form you've written it, this integral is not "improper."  Moreover, your title is misleading:  You're not "integrating an integral."  You're *computing* an integral.

Nevertheless, with a simple substitution, its value can be computed directly:  $\frac{1}{4} \pi  (\text{sgn}(\alpha -\beta )+1)$

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Sloppy question title.

Comment: Sure looks like an improper integral to me.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\sin x \cos y= \frac12[\sin (x+y) + \sin (x-y)]$$

Comment: Aha. So then I will use the summation properties of sin to break this into a sum of integrals.

Answer (score 1):

Use the prosthaphaeresis formula
$$ 2\sin{\alpha x} \cos{\beta x} = \sin{(\alpha+\beta)x} + \sin{(\alpha-\beta)x}. $$
Now, $\alpha+\beta>0$, so we know that
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin{(\alpha+\beta)x}}{x} \, dx = \frac{1}{2}\pi. $$
The other one requires a nonnegative argument for us to use the same formula, and the answer depends therefore on the sign of $\alpha-\beta$, $\operatorname{sgn}{(\alpha-\beta)}$, the whole answer being
$$ \frac{\pi}{4}\left( 1 + \operatorname{sgn}{(\alpha-\beta)} \right). $$